# Laravel 5.8 Nova login test Session is missing expected key [errors]

Tags: laravel, unit-testing, laravel-5, phpunit, laravel-nova

I am trying to write a simple unit test were I try to login with an invalid user in my Laravel Nova but I keep getting this error when I run the test:

> Session is missing expected key [errors].
>
> Failed asserting that false is true.

my test:

```
public function an_invalid_user_can_not_login()
{
    $user = factory(User::class)->create();

    $response = $this->post('/nova/login', [
        'email' => $user->email,
        'password' => 'invalid',
        '_token' => csrf_token(),
    ]);

    $response->assertSessionHasErrors();
    $this->assertGuest();
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

### Edit

it fails on this line:

```
$response->assertSessionHasErrors();
```

Comment: Can we see the code of assertSessionHasErrors()

Comment: @alarmata it's a default function in the laravel testResponse class

Comment: It sounds like the problem is around the session middleware. Try to run it withoutMiddleware() and to see if it fails again.

Answer (score 11):

Try `assertJsonValidationErrors()` instead.

So if its the password you're validating: `$response->assertJsonValidationErrors('password');`

Answer (score 2):

My form request was returning "messages" instead of "errors". So I used the second parameter of the method to pass it.

```
$response->assertJsonValidationErrors('field_name', 'message');
```